# SQL Filter Select Statement if occurs in any column

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter a MS SQL table to show me only those rows which have numeric values.

So as an example, this is the sample table below:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2.0 | 1.0 |
| 3.0 | 1.0 |
| 4.0 | 1.0 |
| 5.0 | A.B |
| 6.0 | 1.0 |
| 7.1 | 1.0 |
| 5.5 | 1.0 |
| 1,2 | 1.0 |

If I do a select statement, I want it to remove 5th and 9th column and return me just 7 results.
However, the following doesn't appear to work:

```
from dbo.Test_Data t
where ISNUMERIC(A) != 0 OR ISNUMERIC(B) !=0;
```

As the OR statement considers that because there is a Numeric occuring in either of the fields, it is counted.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  And, `ISNUMERIC()` should be sufficient for what you are doing -- but you would want:

```
where isnumeric(a) = 1 and isnumeric(b) = 1
```

I would suggest using the `TRY_` functions instead.

```
select t.*
from test_data t
where try_convert(numeric, A) is not null and
      try_convert(numeric, B) is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that logic to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND` instead.  `where ISNUMERIC(A) != 0 AND ISNUMERIC(B) !=0;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LIKE` expressions here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test_Data
WHERE A NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND B NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%';
```